# Case sensitive parquet schema merge in Spark

Tags: apache-spark, parquet

I'm trying to load and analyze some parquet files with Spark.
I'm using `schemaMerge` to load the files since newer files have some extra columns. Also some files have their column names in lower case and others in upper case.

For example

`file1.parquet` has a schema like

```
column1 integer,
column2 integer
```

and `file2.parquet` has something like:

```
Column1 integer,
Column2 integer,
Column3 integer
```

I'm running into an issue with `inferSchema` method of `ParquetFileFormat` class. Schema merging is delegated to `StructType` `merge` method of spark sql. From what I can tell, that method can only work in a case sensitive way.
Internally it uses a map to lookup fields by name and if the cases don't match it will interpret that as a new field. Later, when schema is checked for duplicates, case sensitivity configuration is respected and we end up with having duplicate columns. This results in

```
org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Found duplicate column(s) in the data schema
```

Is there any way to make schema merge case insensitive?

I was expecting to get something like this as a resulting schema:

```
column1 integer,
column2 integer,
Column3 integer
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can set `spark.sql.caseSensitive=true` in your configuration to make Spark SQL schemas case-sensitive. It also affects schema merging.

```
scala> spark.conf.set("spark.sql.caseSensitive","true")

scala> val df = sc.parallelize(1 to 1000).toDF()
df: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [value: int]

scala> df.withColumnRenamed("value","VALUE").write.parquet("test_uc")

scala> df.write.parquet("test_lc")

scala> val df2=spark.read.option("mergeSchema","true").parquet("test_*")
df2: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [value: int, VALUE: int]

scala> val merged = df2.columns.groupBy(_.toLowerCase)
                   .map(t => coalesce(t._2.map(col):_*).as(t._1))
                   .toArray
merged: Array[org.apache.spark.sql.Column] = Array(coalesce(value, VALUE) AS `value`)

scala> df2.select(merged:_*)
res2: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [value: int]

scala> spark.conf.set("spark.sql.caseSensitive","false")

// process your dataframe
```

Comment: Sorry, I was not clear what my expectations were. I was hoping for merge to work in case insensitive way or that there is an option for that directly in Spark. So "value" and "VALUE" would end up being the same column. I guess that is not possible.
I will try your workaround. I'm wondering if select will behave correctly across those files with different schema casing, now that it's set to case sensitive.

Comment: I see the coalesce now, that should handle those multiple files. Thanks! Will try it out.

Comment: If you are case-insensitive, you can't read the files because of the AnalysisException, so you have to set case sensitive and merge the columns "manually" as done in my example. Note that it's simple meta-data wrangling so there's very little cost associated. You can set caseSensitive to false when you have read the file. I'll updated the example to make it clearer.